# Object Created from Custom Event is Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am trying to debug my problem. I have imported a library a co-worker has written that will extract YouTube URLs from a playlist. Once this library is finished the extraction process, it will fire the event `playlistDone` and place the YouTube URLs in the object `OBJ.youtube.videos`. Since my website is very large and complex, I have tested this library on a blank website to verify that it is working.

```
$(document).on('playlistDone', function() {
    console.log( 'done' );
    console.log( OBJ.youtube.videos );
});
```

When I move this code above to my website, the console acknowledges the `playlistDone` custom event, but reports that `OBJ.youtube.videos` is undefined. Can anyone provide any advice as to why this is happening?

Sample of the blank page I used for testing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
        <h1>Video</h1>
        <div id="player" style="width:650px; height:400px;"></div>
        <hr />
        <div style="width:650px; height:80px; border:solid 2px #e8e; overflow:horizontal" id="thumbnails"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="youtube-playlist-lib.js?playlistId=PLA249A8D68B9C95F7&dom=player&thumbnails=thumbnails"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on('playlistDone', function() {
           console.log( 'done' );
           console.log( OBJ.youtube.videos );
        }); 
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can't say without seeing the code that actually creates and populates obj.youtube.videos.  Looks like a bug in their code if it fires `playlistDone` event but there is no data in OBJ.youtube.videos (assuming OBJ is global/window scope)

Comment: @Matt I will try to get permission to post snippets from the library. OBJ.youtube.videos does get populated with data in my test page. It however does not on my website. I am wondering if there could be any possible explanation for this, or perhaps tests I can run on my website.

Comment: `window.OBJ` sounds like an odd place for a library to place something. Are you sure OBJ is not an object passed to the callback function, or otherwise a placeholder variable name from an example snippet? Also, watch you didn't accidentally leave it lowercase somewhere. Oh, and maybe, if its a complex site, you could be using a JS package manager that puts the library somewhere other than global scope?

Comment: @DSKrepps I am 100% sure that OBJ.youtube.videos is the correct object. I did another test where instead of waiting for the custom `playlistDone` event to fire I added a delay of 5000ms and then `console.log(OBJ.youtube.videos);` which did confirm that my object did get populated.

Comment: @DSKrepps I am just confused why `OBJ.youtube.videos` is not populated when the custom event is fired, and instead is populated XXXX-ms later.

Comment: Is your complex website running slower than your test one? I've run into bugs before for that reason alone. It seems the event is being fired too early in the library, and the trigger should be moved to after OBJ is set. Whatever code is in between is taking longer.

Comment: @DSKrepps The code doesn't appear to be running slower upon visual inspection. Is there a way to verify this via code? I checked the library, and it is triggering the event after the OBJ is set.

Comment: Well, I can't really think of anything else with only the information I have, not looking at the library myself. I would pass the OBJ straight to the event, though, instead of a global. `...trigger( 'playlistDone', OBJ)` in the library and then `...on('playlistDone',function(e,OBJ){...` I believe is the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that there was nothing wrong with the code at all. Instead, Chrome was caching an older version of the library.

Answer (score 1):

`OBJ.youtube.video` is created in `youtube-playlist-lib.js`. So if you try to use it before you include `youtube-playlist-lib.js` you will get an error, becuase you are trying to use when it is not set.

Make sure you use it **after** you include `youtube-playlist-lib.js`.

Comment: Yup, I am using `OBJ.youtube.video` after I have included `youtube-playlist-lib.js`. Odd thing is that I am receiving the custom event `playstlistDone` from the library, but am not receiving the populated `OBJ.youtube.video`.

Comment: I would debug it using firebug. Add a breakpoint before you use `OBJ.youtube.video` and check why it's undefined.